# How to set background color of layer in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cclayer

I've been writing a game using cocos2d-x and ran into an issue with changing the background color. I found an [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) in cocos2d, but apparently this only applies to cocos2d which is written in Obj-c. Basically the idea is to use a CCLayerColor instead of CCLayer, and when the constructor gets fired set the color.

Does anyone know how to change the background color in cocos2d-x? Seems like it would be pretty simple, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**2.X or below**

Extend [`CCLayerColor`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2/da/d2c/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_layer_color.html) instead of [`CCLayer`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2/da/d2c/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_layer_color.html#ad6797e9d96ccfc5736e93e94e09fc74a). For example,

```
class CommonScene : public cocos2d::CCLayerColor
{
public:
...
}
```

Initialize with this code:

```
bool CommonScene::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if( !CCLayerColor::initWithColor(ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)) ) //RGBA
    {
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to change background use the [`setColor`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2/da/d2c/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_layer_color.html#ad6797e9d96ccfc5736e93e94e09fc74a) method from `CCLayerColor`.  For example,

```
this->setColor(ccc3(255, 255, 255));
```

**3.0 or above**

Modify above code like this:

Header file (.h)

```
class CommonScene : public cocos2d::LayerColor
```

Source file (.cpp)

```
if( !LayerColor::initWithColor(Color4B(255,255,255,255)) )
```

Comment: I am also facing this issue. How did you solve it? If I change according to this. I am getting error as in below question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587536/not-able-to-change-the-background-of-the-scene-in-cocos2dx-android

Answer (score 10):

In cocos2d-x v.3.x, you can add a LayerColor inside the init method like this:

```
auto bg = cocos2d::LayerColor::create(Color4B(53, 53, 53, 255));
this->addChild(bg);
```

Comment: By this way, cocos2d-x displays wrong color. If i use `LayerColor::create(Color4B(255, 0, 0, 255))` , the displayed color is `fb0007` not `ff0000`

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way I could locate that does not impact performance, is to simply do:

```
glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
```

Somewhere in your Scene init() function.  This way you do not have to change to a LayerColor and performance is not affected either.  Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

**For Cocos2d-x v3.0**

In *.h

```
class PlayScene : public cocos2d::LayerColor
```

In *.cpp

```
bool PlayScene::init()
{
    if ( !LayerColor::initWithColor(Color4B(255, 255, 255, 255) )) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```